# What HTTP status codes count as success in jQuery.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) doesn't seem to specify exactly what is meant by 'success' in jQuery.ajax.  Is it any 2xx code?  Only 200?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From the source code:

```
if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 ) {
```

So any 2xx and under special circumstances 304 as well. 304 has some extra handling though, check the source for more info.

Comment: Angular js considers 304 a error, and triggers the error event

Answer (score 4):

You'll find this in the done callback.  A success is any status greater than or equal to 200 and less than 300.    A notmodified (304) is also viewed as a success.