# What does plain ajax do with status code 300?

Tags: javascript, ajax, httpresponse

Basically, not talking about library abstractions, how are responses in the 300 family handled by vanilla ajax calls (like `XMLHttpRequest`)?

Does the internal handler follow the redirect seamlessly, delivering the final result to the JS object, or does it simply return with the `responseText` of the server and we have to handle the second request ourselves?

I have to say the latter makes a heck of a lot more sense but on the other hand it'd be nice for the browser to handle it. Ultimately I don't know, and [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ajaxintro3/) article likes to tell us how we don't need to know about it, whilst jQuery [seems to agree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296811/what-http-status-codes-count-as-success-in-jquery-ajax).

Comment: The browser handles the redirect before returning the final response to the AJAX handler. The server's response is for the browser to redirect, so the browser's doing just that

Comment: if you have a reference you could get get an accepted answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no reference, I just know from experience that's how it's handled. Hopefully someone can shed some real light on this