# Ajax request hitting error function before HandleUnauthorizedRequest

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, cordova

I have an `PhoneGap` app that is communicating with a `C#` service for it's data. The user has to be logged in for them to access any of this so I have a `AuthorizeAttribute` on my controller. This works fine and rightly, throws an to my app. The problem for me is that in my `AuthorizeAttribute` I am overriding the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method and it ***should*** be returning a 401. In fact, it probably is, it's just that the Ajax handler hits the error function before my override method has returned.

### AuthorizeAttribute

```
public class AppCustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

### Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url + "checkin/app/info",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(d) {
        // Do stuff
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        app.showError(errorThrown); // Status code is 0
    }
});
```

When I look at the `Network` requests, it seems that my get request is **cancelled**. Originally, I assumed this is because my authorize attribute is causing it cancel the request, but then, it seems to cancel before it hits my handler.

Comment: Can't quite find the docs but I'm pretty sure a 401 is counted as an error response by jQuery.ajax.

Comment: Yes, yes it does [What HTTP status codes count as success in jQuery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296811/what-http-status-codes-count-as-success-in-jquery-ajax)

Comment: with concern to *"In fact, it probably is"* fire up [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and inspect the HTTP

Comment: @Liam As mentioned in the question. It's cancelled, the ajax error function is entered before my override method

Comment: So what's the HTTP response code your getting?

Comment: @Liam I get 0, presumably because it's cancelled

Comment: A zero could be a timeout. How long are you debugging your code for? A zero normally means, I'm not returning anything, at all. The connection is simply dead.

Comment: @Liam Response is instantaneous.

Comment: this all points at your URL being incorrect or your doing a GET on a URL that only accepts POSTs.

Comment: @Liam I thought this too. But if I am logged in, it works correctly, returning a JsonResult.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is answerable without debugging all your code, which obviously isn't possible. I am also, out of ideas.....Hope you get the solution! :)

Comment: @Liam Thanks for your help. It's been good to eliminate all that we have as possible answers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because of the Same Origin Policy. Check this out:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: It's not to do with `Same Origin Policy`. I'm testing this on Chrome with disabled security settings, but +1 as it may be the solution for others in future.

Comment: Oh so it was because of that? :)

Comment: No, it was because of the reason in my answer. But likelihood is that people with the same problem coming to the question will be looking for your answer opposed to mine. I'd rather yours is the first they see.

Answer (score 2):

Just in order to close the complete the question, the reason I was seeing a response code of 0 is because:

> A status code of "0" usually means the user navigated to a different
>   page before the AJAX call completed

I got this from ***[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/http-status-code-0-what-does-this-mean-in-ms-xmlhttp)***, which has over 70,000 views at the time of writing, so I guess this problem can occur a lot. This obviously led me to look at what could be causing my app to navigate elsewhere and sure enough, in my code I had:

```
$('[data-role=page]').on('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
if ($(location).attr('pathname').indexOf('login.html') == -1)
    if (window.localStorage['UserName'] == null || window.localStorage['Password'] == null) 
        window.location = "login.html";
}):
```

As a workaround from the early stages of development from the app as a primitive type of checking the user was actually logged in.